# How does Amazon SNS manage CloudWatch log streams for delivery status?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

Amazon AWS SNS has a feature allowing delivery status of mobile push notifications to be logged in CloudWatch. This is documented briefly here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-msg-status.html

My goal is to track delivery success of every push notification sent from our system.

I have followed these instructions and am seeing log events coming in nicely. Each SNS application endpoint has its own CloudWatch Log Group. In my case, I have both an Android and an iOS endpoint, and there appear to be different groups for successes and failures, so I have up to four Log Groups to monitor.

Within the CloudWatch Log Groups are Log Streams. SNS seems to create arbitrary, numerically named Log Streams. My question is **whether there is any pattern being followed here**, or even better **if I can control the name of these streams**? I don't see this in the documentation.

For example, after sending a bunch of messages to my small set of test devices, I have the following Log Groups and Streams (the numbers are the names of the streams):

```
sns/us-east-1/xxxxx/app/APNS_SANDBOX/App-iOS-Dev
    322
    342
    702
    704

sns/us-east-1/xxxxx/app/GCM/App-Android-Dev
    264
    122

sns/us-east-1/xxxxx/app/GCM/App-Android-Dev/Failure
    333
    99
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?